# Links to other web pages links to same page

Tags: html, css

I got two HTML headings, one at the upper right corner and on on the upper left. For some reason, h1:s link merge to h2:s link and I can't figure out why.

My CSS:

```
h1{
   font-size: 35px;
   color: black;
   position: fixed;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   text-align: left;
 }  

h2{
   font-size: 35px;
   color: black;
   position: fixed;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   text-align: right;
  }
```

My HTML:

```
<a href="projects.html"><h1>my work</h1></a> 
<a href="projects2.html"><h2>other work</h2></a>
```

When I remove position: fixed; from the CSS, the links work properly

Comment: Just a note: Your use of HTML header tags (h1, h2) is really wrong in these cases - concerning semantics/content, SEO and accessibility. Headers should *never* link to other pages, not even link to other positions on the same page, but should function as headers for the contents (text, images, whatever) that follows immediately after them, and they should be hierarchically organized in their levels (h1/h2/h3 etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `left:0px` and `right:0px` on both `h1` and `h2` you extends the header from left to right, one cover the other.

Set only `left` on one and only `right` on the other.

```css
h1{

   left: 0;

   font-size: 35px;
   color: black;
   position: fixed;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   text-align: left;
   background-color:green;
 }  

h2{

   
   right: 0;

   font-size: 35px;
   color: black;
   position: fixed;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   text-align: right;
   background-color:red;
  }
```

```html
<a href="projects.html"><h1>my work</h1></a> 
<a href="projects2.html"><h2>other work</h2></a>
```